# Access IPs who's subnets differ

Tags: networking, subnet, ipv4

I have one system that is on 10.0.x.21 and another that is on 10.0.y.21

Is there a simple way to allow those two IPs to communicate? I am trying to create a setup where X and Y can both potentially vary from 0-255 and any combination of x and y will still allow for the systems to communicate.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Two obvious answers: (1) Make it all one network by setting netmask to 255.255.0.0 (so the addresses are /16 instead of /24).  (2) Connect the subnets with a router.

Comment: Thank you! I can't use a router. But I had assumed that if I set the netmask to 255.255.0.0 then they would be reachable. I'm still a little new to networking, but this made sense to me. Yet, even with that in place, I was unable to ping from my Windows PC (192.168.2.50) to the device on the other end (192.168.0.21). Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Well, you haven’t really given us much information about your configuration.  What’s the physical connection between the two systems?  Is it all one network?  Obviously, if there’s no physical / electrical connectivity, then the systems cannot communicate. … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Also, I’m looking at this as an issue of wired networking.  If you’re talking about Wi-Fi, please say so.

Comment: Sorry... Yes! Everything is physically connected via Ethernet and a switch, all on one network. I have a PC/Windows Server on 192.168.1.50 and a PLC on 192.168.1.*** and then a few other devices on 192.168.2.21 and 192.168.3.21. Due to other reasons, I can't really change their IP addresses. Given this information, I'm assuming what you recommended "should" work and I'm just configuring something incorrectly.  Sorry, again! I'm relatively new to networking.

Comment: Well, you may be missing something obvious, but I guess I am too.  It seems to me that what you’ve done should work.  I probably won’t be able to help you get any farther; I suggest that you [edit] your question to include the information you’ve posted as comments, and maybe add a drawing of the configuration, and hope that somebody else sees it and helps you. One last question I would raise is whether you’ve done anything to the switch to “tell” it that the netmask is 255.255.0.0, but I don’t know exactly what you would need to do (if anything).  Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a simple way to allow those two IPs to communicate?

Yes, a router. Routers route between subnets.

Assuming a /24 network mask for each of your addresses, they belong to different subnets (10.0.x.0/24 and 10.0.y.0/24), requiring a router in between.

If you use a /16 network mask, both IP addresses belong to the same subnet and talk to each other directly, so you can use a simple L2 switch or a direct cable.

The same network mask needs to be used for all devices in a subnet.